# static_assert presence of a member in an incomplete type

Tags: c++, static-assert, incomplete-type

Given the following example:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

template <typename T, typename = void>
struct has_name: std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct has_name<T, decltype(std::declval<T>().name, void())>: std::true_type {};

template <typename T>
struct MyContainer {
    static_assert(has_name<T>::value);
    std::vector<T> elements;
};

struct Parent;
struct Child;

struct Parent {
    std::string name;
    MyContainer<Child> children;
};

struct Child {
    std::string name;
    MyContainer<Parent> parents;
};
```

This does not compile because `Child` in `MyContainer<Child>` inside `Parent` is an incomplete type, so the `static_assert` that checks for a `name` member fails. How can I perform assertions about incomplete types or if anything here is bad practice, what should I do instead?

(I am aware that the example is a bit contrived, I tried to reduce my real world scenario to a minimum.)

Comment: I guess this is a bad example, parents and children would need to contain each other which is not possible. But yes it can be solved with pointers, the problem remains however. Using CRTP, you mean `Parent` should have a template parameter T which is then filled with `Child`?

Comment: Perhaps moving the assertion to some member function of `MyContainer` would fix your actual issue (by delaying the check until later), but this is just guesswork. Hard to say anything without a more realistic example.

Comment: I think what is really biting you is the circular dependency of your declarations. Not the templates and/or the static_assert. You already have a problem when you do this `struct Parent { Child child; }; struct Child {Parent parent;}`.  Or add `template<> struct has_name<Parent> : std::true_type {};` and `template<> struct has_name<Child> : std::true_type {};` just after the forward declarations of Parent/Child (which might not be gooe enough because this is prone to developer error)